# How to attach outer function to $routeProvider resolve?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This code works fine:

```
$routeProvider.when('/clients',
        {
            templateUrl:'/views/clients.html',
            controller:'clientsController',
            resolve: {
                rights: function ($rootScope, apiService) {
                    var userInfo = localStorage.getItem("connectionInfo");
                    if (userInfo) {
                        userInfo = JSON.parse(userInfo);
                        var promiseObj= apiService.getUsersRights(userInfo.auth_token);
                        promiseObj.then(function(value) {
                            console.log(value);
                            $rootScope.user.rights = value.values.rights;
                            return value.values.rights;
                        });
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I want to use this function many times, but when I try this, it doesn't work. It throws Injection error.

```
function userRightsResolver ($rootScope, apiService) {
    var userInfo = localStorage.getItem("connectionInfo");
    if (userInfo) {
        userInfo = JSON.parse(userInfo);
        var promiseObj= apiService.getUsersRights(userInfo.auth_token);
        promiseObj.then(function(value) {
            console.log(value);
            $rootScope.user.rights = value.values.rights;
            return value.values.rights;
        });
    } else {
       return null;
    }
}

$routeProvider.when('/clients',
        {
            templateUrl:'/views/clients.html',
            controller:'clientsController',
            resolve: {
                rights: userRightsResolver($rootScope, apiService)
            }
        });
```

I am new to angularJS. How to make it right?

Comment: please include the error and the code surrounding the route. Is it in a `.config`? `.run`?

Comment: @jm_____, It is in .config. Error is Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: services and factories cannot be injected into `.config` only providers can be.

Comment: have you tried just `rights: userRightsResolver`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try the following approach, which I've used in my apps.

Create a `routeResolve` object above your routes, and give it methods representing the resolve functions you'll reuse:

```
var routeResolve = {
  rights: ['$rootScope', 'apiService', function($rootScope, apiService) {
    var userInfo = localStorage.getItem("connectionInfo");
    if (userInfo) {
      userInfo = JSON.parse(userInfo);
      var promiseObj= apiService.getUsersRights(userInfo.auth_token);
      promiseObj.then(function(value) {
        console.log(value);
        $rootScope.user.rights = value.values.rights;
        return value.values.rights;
      });
    } else {
       return null;
    }
  }],
  anotherMethod: [function() {...}]
};
```

Then in your route, you can do:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/clients', {
     templateUrl:'/views/clients.html',
     controller:'clientsController',
     resolve: {
       rights: routeResolve.rights
     }
  });
```

Comment: Almost alright, but I come to `clientsController` before `routeResolve`. That's why there is no rights in `$rootScope.user.rights` when I go inside controller.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I should return the whole Promise object: `promiseObj` after `then(...)` handler and I must not to return anything inside `then(...)` handler.